# Generate range of strings

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Hi, everyone.
I need you help with this problem.
I need to create a bunch of serial numbers in one of my tables and for that I want to use stored procedure. So I want to pass FirstSN and LastSN as parameters to the SP and it inserts N records into my table. A serial number consists of prefix and an incremental part.
For example, I send SN0001 as FirstSN and SN0100 as LastSN and it should insert the following:
SN0001
SN0002
SN0003
...
SN0099
SN0100

How can I do that without using loops?

P.s. I am using oracle 11.2.0

Comment: Multisync's answer below is 100% correct but allow me to propose another solution... If the record has a primary key field (for instance a part ID) create a virtual column with a concatenation of that with the SN prefix or use a sequence object. It guarantees your SN #s will be unique and is a scalable option with minimal intervention (or even an SP) required.

Comment: @mmmmmpie the serial number is a Primary key in this table.
The problem is that in one database I have table with ranges SN001 - SN100, SN123 - SN135, ...
And in this database I need to create serial numbers itself

Comment: use a SEQUENCE along with your prefix.should solve your problem.refer SEQUENCES in oracle library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 'SN' || lpad(lvl, length('100')+1, '0') from (select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 100);
```

Comment: The problem is that the incremental part is not always 4 symbols long
Although, this could probably work, if I pass prefix and first incremental part and last incremental part
So if noone proposes anything better, this would be the accepted answer!

Comment: @Maiorov Yury The main idea is to how generate numbers. Anyway, I've updated the answer. You may use LPAD for example to add zeros to the left.